# Difficulty in understanding the function and the function parameters

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, fingerprint

I am trying to build a program on Minutiae based fingerprint verification and for pre-processing I need to orient the ridges and I found a related function on the internet but could not understand it properly.

I tried reading many research papers on minutiae extraction.

This is the function I found on the internet

```
def ridge_orient(im, gradientsigma, blocksigma, orientsmoothsigma):

rows,cols = im.shape;
#Calculate image gradients.
sze = np.fix(6*gradientsigma);
if np.remainder(sze,2) == 0:
    sze = sze+1;

gauss = cv2.getGaussianKernel(np.int(sze),gradientsigma);
f = gauss * gauss.T;

fy,fx = np.gradient(f);     #Gradient of Gaussian

#Gx = ndimage.convolve(np.double(im),fx);
#Gy = ndimage.convolve(np.double(im),fy);

Gx = signal.convolve2d(im,fx,mode='same');    
Gy = signal.convolve2d(im,fy,mode='same');

Gxx = np.power(Gx,2);
Gyy = np.power(Gy,2);
Gxy = Gx*Gy;

#Now smooth the covariance data to perform a weighted summation of the data.    

sze = np.fix(6*blocksigma);

gauss = cv2.getGaussianKernel(np.int(sze),blocksigma);
f = gauss * gauss.T;

Gxx = ndimage.convolve(Gxx,f);
Gyy = ndimage.convolve(Gyy,f);
Gxy = 2*ndimage.convolve(Gxy,f);

# Analytic solution of principal direction
denom = np.sqrt(np.power(Gxy,2) + np.power((Gxx - Gyy),2)) + np.finfo(float).eps;

sin2theta = Gxy/denom;            # Sine and cosine of doubled angles
cos2theta = (Gxx-Gyy)/denom;


if orientsmoothsigma:
    sze = np.fix(6*orientsmoothsigma);
    if np.remainder(sze,2) == 0:
        sze = sze+1;    
    gauss = cv2.getGaussianKernel(np.int(sze),orientsmoothsigma);
    f = gauss * gauss.T;
    cos2theta = ndimage.convolve(cos2theta,f); # Smoothed sine and cosine of
    sin2theta = ndimage.convolve(sin2theta,f); # doubled angles

orientim = np.pi/2 + np.arctan2(sin2theta,cos2theta)/2;
return(orientim);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code computes the [structure tensor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor), a method to compute the local orientation in a robust way. It obtains, per pixel, a symmetric 2x2 matrix (tensor) (variables `Gxx`, `Gyy` and `Gxy`) whose eigenvectors indicate local orientation and whose eigenvalues indicate strength of local variation. Because it returns a matrix rather than a simple gradient vector, you can distinguish uniform regions from structures like a cross, neither of which has a strong gradient, but the cross has a strong local variation.

---

## Some criticism about the code

```
fy,fx = np.gradient(f);
```

is a really bad way of obtaining a Gaussian derivative kernel. Here you just lose all the benefits of a Gaussian gradient, and instead compute a finite difference approximation to the gradient.

Next, the code doesn’t use the separability of the Gaussian to reduce computational complexity, which is also a shame.

In [this blog post](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22) I go over the theory of Gaussian filtering and Gaussian derivatives, and in [this other one](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/150) I detail some practical aspects (using MATLAB, but this should readily extend to Python).